# Error in file decrypting

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, encryption, c++-cli

I am encrypting and decrypting a file. Below is the code.

**Encryption code**

```
void InformationWriter::writeContacts(System::String ^phone, System::String ^email)
{
        //Write the file
        StreamWriter ^originalTextWriter = gcnew StreamWriter("contacts.dat",false);
        originalTextWriter->WriteLine(phone);
        originalTextWriter->WriteLine(email);
        originalTextWriter->Close();


        //Encrypt the file
        FileStream ^fileWriter = gcnew FileStream("contacts2.dat",FileMode::Create,FileAccess::Write);


        DESCryptoServiceProvider ^crypto = gcnew DESCryptoServiceProvider();

        crypto->Key = ASCIIEncoding::ASCII->GetBytes("Intru235");
        crypto->IV = ASCIIEncoding::ASCII->GetBytes("Intru235");

        CryptoStream ^cStream = gcnew CryptoStream(fileWriter,crypto->CreateEncryptor(),CryptoStreamMode::Write);


        //array<System::Byte>^ phoneBytes = ASCIIEncoding::ASCII->GetBytes(phone);
        FileStream ^input = gcnew FileStream("contacts.dat",FileMode::Open); //Open the file to be encrypted
        int data = 0;

        while((data=input->ReadByte()!=-1))
        {
            cStream->WriteByte((System::Byte)data);
        }

        input->Close();
        cStream->Close();
        fileWriter->Close();

        System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show("Data Saved");



}
```

**Decryption Code**

void InformationReader::readInformation()
{
    System::String ^password = "Intru235";

```
FileStream ^stream = gcnew FileStream("contacts2.dat",FileMode::Open,FileAccess::Read);

array<System::Byte>^data = File::ReadAllBytes("contacts2.dat");
System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show(System::Text::Encoding::Default->GetString(data));

DESCryptoServiceProvider ^crypto = gcnew DESCryptoServiceProvider();
crypto->Key = ASCIIEncoding::ASCII->GetBytes(password);
crypto->IV = ASCIIEncoding::ASCII->GetBytes(password);

CryptoStream ^crypStream = gcnew CryptoStream(stream,crypto->CreateDecryptor(),CryptoStreamMode::Read);

StreamReader ^reader = gcnew StreamReader(crypStream);
phoneNumber = reader->ReadLine();
email = reader->ReadLine();

crypStream->Close();
reader->Close();
}
```

Even though my file writing thing works as should be, the reading one is having issues. When I read things, I only get blank Lines! I know the program has read "something" because the lines are blank (spaces).

What am I doing wrong in this decrypt or thing?

**Update**

The decryption code above is edited. Now I am trying to read the bytes as bytes but when I display them as text (using below code), I only get the following

```
System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show(System::Text::Encoding::Default->GetString(data));
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried reading all the lines present in the `reader`?  You appear to be looking at two lines only.  I also note that you are encrypting bytes: `WriteByte` but reading text: `ReadLine`.  Better to use bytes for both, and afterwards convert the bytes back into text.

Comment: @rossum: wow, this is interesting. Lets see

Comment: @rossum: Hi, I updated the code and question. Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

First check your encryption code.  Find some DES test vectors and run then through your encryption method.  Don't use characters, but check on the byte level.

When you are sure that your encryption method is working, use your decryption method to decrypt one of the test vectors, and check that the bytes it gives you back are the same bytes that you encrypted in the first place.  Again, use bytes instead of characters.  Using characters can introduce a great many errors too early in the process.

When you can encrypt and decrypt a byte array successfully, then try characters.  Make very sure that you use the same character conversion on both sides.  Your current encryption method specifies ASCII for Key and IV, but appears to go straight to bytes for the plaintext.  Your decryption function does not specify an encoding for the decrypted plaintext either.  That is not good practice.  Specify an encoding at both sides, UTF-8 for preference though it will depend on what format your data is currently held in.

The reason I emphasised byte level checking before was to avoid all the extra complications with character encodings: BOM or not, different EoL markers, 0x00 bytes to mark the end of a string or not etc.  Get it working with bytes first, then introduce character encoding.  Find and fix one problem at a time.